# Bootstrap 4 snippet not running validation code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, code-snippets

I have questions I was trying to ask by basing examples on the [custom styles section of the Bootstrap 4 form page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#custom-styles), however I find that I am unable to get a snippet working for that base form. Typing anything in the last three fields for example should make the validation message disappear. Not sure what I am missing here.

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<form class="container" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom03">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="City" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid city.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom04">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="State" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid state.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Zip" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid zip.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the dependencies you're using. Replace your `link` and `script` tags with these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<form class="container" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom03">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="City" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid city.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom04">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="State" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid state.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Zip" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid zip.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sweet.. now I can start asking my actual questions. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Just getting it to work is a battle in itself sometimes. Good luck.